# sharepoint note board - a way to push comments?

Tags: ajax, sharepoint

currently, in sharepoint 2010, comments when posted to a note board web part, are not visible to other viewers until they refresh. does anyone know of a way to add this funcitonality? is this even possible? are there any 3rd party vendors who might? my searches have not turned up anything.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but it is tricky - what you need is a JavaScript event handler and the web part wrapped in a DIV with an ID - when something changes, you do a redirect to the same page. Note: this has to be done with designer on the page itself.

There is another way that you can do it using an HTTP Handler (like we do for the Contnent Editor Web Part).

Hope that helps,

David M. Sterling
Sterling International Consulting Group
www.sterling-consulting.com
davidmsterling.blogspot.com

Comment: hi david, thanks for the reply. could you explain a bit more the technique of using an http handler?

many thanks